# Is it allowed to link to a site that contains a link to Facebook?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, app-store-connect

The iOS and Mac OS AppStore terms are strict on links to outside sources and shops. If I would link from my iOS app to a page which contains a link to Facebook or Twitter, would that violate the store's terms?

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you sell items on the page or make money from someone clicking on it. Pages that link to Facebook and Twitter are fine.